# Causative verb usage in sentence

Tags: grammaticality, causative-have

Can i write
 "having had him seat on  chair,he started telling story".
here first have is participle and second had is used as causative.is it correct to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_Having had him **sit** on **a** chair, he started telling **a** story.

People are divided over whether or not that is acceptable. Some call it a "dangling participle construction", and object to it because the subject of the participle *having* is clearly not the same as the subject of the main clause *he*.

Other people use constructions like this without any problem.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the sentence is a bit tortured regardless of its correctness.  There are many ways to rewrite it, with varying degrees of subtle difference in meaning, but I'd consider something like "We offered him a chair and he sat down.  Then he began his story."

Answer (score 1):

The use of "having had" may be correct. However the sentence contains multiple other errors. I think you meant something like

> Having had him sit on a chair, he started to tell a story.

This would appear to be a dangling participle.  The subject of the main sentence is "He", this is also the implied subject of the participle phrase.  But that doesn't make sense.  This could be fixed by some kind of passive construction, but at this point you should realise that the sentence has become unreadable. You need to rephrase completely, probably using two or more sentences.